# Google PieChart hover over specific slices trigger a div change

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a simple Google Piechart and a div with text:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// loading the visualization module
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});

// function to compose and draw the chart
function trilulilu () {
    // variable with the data, an array of array's 
    // in which the first position are the column names
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Food', 'How much people like it'],
        ['Sausage', 20],
        ['Pizza', 40],
        ['Fish n Fries', 5],
        ['Sushi', 30],
        ['Ciorba', 5],

    ]);

    // options for chart display
    var options = {
        title: 'Food', // chart title
        is3D: true // false for 2d and true for 3d. Default is false
    };

    // create a new PieChart object that receives 
    // as param a div where the chart will be rendered
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // draw with args and options
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

// function to be called after loading
google.setOnLoadCallback(trilulilu);
</script>
```

Information related to the chart

Is is possible when I hover the mouse over the sushi slice of the chart to trigger a change via Javascript in the div with id="sushi" (a change in the background color for instance)?

Comment: it is possible, using the following [chart events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#events): `onmouseover` & `onmouseout`. each event receives the data table row index of the slice being hovered. you can use the row index to get the value of the slice from the data table. from which you can use as the id to find the `<div>` that should be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating a hover effect on the sushi slice of a Google PieChart to change the background color of a `div` with an `id` of your choice. In this case `sushi`. Take a look:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google PieChart Hover Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(trilulilu);
      
      function trilulilu() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Food', 'How much people like it'],
          ['Sausage', 20],
          ['Pizza', 40],
          ['Fish n Fries', 5],
          ['Sushi', 30],
          ['Ciorba', 5],
        ]);
      
        var options = {
          title: 'Food',
          is3D: true
        };
      
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
      
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(e) {
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'Sushi') {
            document.getElementById('sushi').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
          }
        });
      
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function(e) {
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'Sushi') {
            document.getElementById('sushi').style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 175px;"></div>
    <div id="sushi">Information related to the chart</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will change the background color of the div to yellow when hovering over the sushi slice and reset it when the mouse leaves the slice. Make sure you got a `div` with id `sushi` in your HTML.

Comment: Perfect! It works! But is it possible to automatize a bit, in your chart the slice with the highest percentage - pizza with 40% - to trigger automatically the change in div color not only when hovering over it? Thank you.